# Cannot set cookie path to the root directory with Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

On localhost. Using Firefox 88.0 (Private window). My document tree:

```
/index.html
/page1/index.php
/page2/index.php
```

Here's my JS to set cookies (on `page1`):

```
function setCookie(name, value) {
  document.cookie = name + "=" + value;
  document.cookie = "path=/";
}
```

Which (I think) overwrites the cookie path to `/` every time I call the function. At the beginning of the same JS file I have: `alert(document.cookie);`. It displays the full cookie as I save it, including `path=/`.

On the homepage (`/index.html`) I have: `<script>alert(document.cookie);</script>`. But it displays an empty alert. I don't see the cookies. But if I go back to the `page1` then I see the cookies again. Why is this?

I've also tried (solutions from other SO answers):

- visiting 127.0.0.1 - didn't work (port is always 80).
- Uploading to a web server. Same result as above.
- visiting the localhost (`localhost` and `127.0.0.1`) on Chrome.

Couldn't resolve. Could anyone help please? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try to call **setupCookie()** in your main index.html file and also set your cookie expiry.

Comment: I'll need the cookie throughout the entire website. I tried to access from the homepage just to test if it worked. I'll mainly need it on `/page2/index.php`

Comment: If the first method is not working then the other solution is that to call setcookie  in every page with condition that cookie is already set or not

Comment: @Sagar I don't see how that'll solve my problem. I need to get the data from page1 to page2 and other pages. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently I have to set the path at the time of setting the cookie, not using `document.cookie` after the cookie has already been set.

This got the problem fixed:

```
function setCookie(name, value) {
  document.cookie = name + "=" + value + ";path=/"; //Set the path while setting the Value.
}
```